# SQLAlchemy - Add Event Listener to All Models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

New to Python and trying to figure out a clean way to add event listeners to all (or at least most) models in my FastAPI app. I want to do something like the following but just can't figure out the right place to put it:

```
hook_models = set()
hook_models.add(models.Foo)
hook_models.add(models.Bar)
hook_models.add(models.Baz)

for model in hook_models:
    @event.listens_for(model, "after_insert")
    def insert_record(mapper: Mapper, connection: Connection, target: models.Base):
        do_something(target, "insert")

    @event.listens_for(model, "after_update")
    def update_record(mapper: Mapper, connection: Connection, target: models.Base):
        do_something(target, "update")
```

Comment: I think that the easiest way is to create a new baseclass to which you register the `@event.listens_for` with `propagate=True` and use that baseclass for you models.

Comment: @rfkortekaas can you give a minimum exmaple of working  code, because i tried what you said  but it did not work.